# Google Services not working on Tablets

Tags: android, tablet, google-signin, google-authentication

As far as I'm aware, there is no difference between android for phones and android for tablets (with the exception of phone calls and texting). However, when I attempt to log into my app on a physical tablet, I receive an error `handleSignInResult:false` while on a mobile phone I am able to log in.

I've listed the devices at the bottom. Signing in works on tablet emulators, phone emulators, and physical phones. It does not work on physical tablets.

What I've tried:

- I've tried using the same account I used on the phone, on the tablet.
- I've tried using different accounts on the tablet.
- I've tried re-syncing the accounts on the tablet (including removing and re-adding).
- I've tried regenerating my OAuth keys on the google api console page and re-downloading the oath json files.
- I've tried using a different physical tablet.

I don't know how to force the app to output the exact reason why the sign in result is false. Which would be a good place to start.

---

**EDIT:**
I've manually bypassed google-log in when sign-in returns false and it seems like my **Google Maps** activity is not working either (Google logo, but blank tiles otherwise). The maps activity also works fine on my physical phones, as well as on both types of emulators. Is it possible that there is some sort of built-in security that is preventing the device from communicating with Play services?

(The devices do have a working internet connection.)

Comment: I have been facing the same issue lately. Earlier (earlier versions of Google play services) used to work fine. It is version 9877000 that I am facing the exact same issue, must be an issue on the play services library end.